# How to run intellij's cucumber-java plugin locally

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, intellij-plugin

I am using Intellij cucumber-java plugin. After updating to cucumber-jvm 3, it fails to navigate to step definitions from feature files since I am using new argument placeholders now (e.g., `"I have {int} cukes in my {string}"` instead of `"^I have (\d+) cukes in my (.*?)$"`).

I would like to tweak cucumber-java plugin but I don't really get it how to build and run intellij's plugin locally. I cloned the plugins from https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins, cloned intellij community edition and set up plugin devKit. At this point I don't see how to build and run cucumber-java plugin locally. I tried to create a new plugin to extend cucumber-java but there is no extension points in cucumber-java.

Is it dead-end or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195098

Answer (score 1):

*I know it is old question, but mby someone will find this answer usefull.*

Not long ago I actually managed to tweak the cucumber plugin (gherkin) for intelliJ, so mby same way will work for cucumber-java plugin.

I had a problem with very complex step definitions, when I used many optional regexps.
eg. If I had something like this in my stepdef **"(| using user \"([^\"]*)\" and password \"([^\"]*)\")"** then autocompletion was failing and showed just **param** for the rest of the step, but nvm why I needed to "repair" the plugin - this is what I've done to make it work for me:

1. I converted the plugin from devkit way to gradle based plugin, this article was very usefull for me: [adding-gradle-support-to-an-existing-devkit-based-intellij-platform-plugin](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system/prerequisites.html#adding-gradle-support-to-an-existing-devkit-based-intellij-platform-plugin)
2. I got rid of all compilation issues, I had to change one class from kotlin to java, and fix some issues with properties.

After that I was able to build the plugin and simply install compiled jar by hand in intelliJ, what I have never achived is to debug the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is looking for an answer: cucumber-java plugin doesn't have extension points. The solution is not to use cucumber expression but stick to regex. Regex are still working for cucumber 3.